# Null check in the Queryexpression in crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am using Queryexpression object in the CRM 2011, I am putting null condition in the condition statement but I found the below error :

```
Condition for attribute 'customer_term_sheet.qdb_status': null is not a valid value for an attribute. Use 'Null' or 'NotNull' conditions instead.
```

please suggest me, how can I resolve ?

Below is my code :

```
QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression();
qe.EntityName = "customer_term_sheet";
qe.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "status" });

ConditionExpression CondOppId = new ConditionExpression();
CondOppId.AttributeName = "status";
CondOppId.Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal;

// This is the line in question
CondOppId.Values.Add(null);

FilterExpression filter = new FilterExpression();
filter.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;
filter.Conditions.AddRange(new ConditionExpression[] { CondOppId });
qe.Criteria = filter;
RetrieveMultipleRequest request = new RetrieveMultipleRequest();
request.Query = qe;
RetrieveMultipleResponse response = (RetrieveMultipleResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `ConditionOperator.Null`, it's not necessary to specify a value with this operator.

```
ConditionExpression CondOppId = new ConditionExpression();
CondOppId.AttributeName = "qdb_status";
CondOppId.Operator = ConditionOperator.Null;
```